# How do I loop through a folder of PDF files to extract text from a fillable form with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pypdf

I'd like to loop through a folder with several fillable PDF forms to extract the text from the fields. I've figured out how extract the text and append to a data frame. I need to create the loop to iterate through all the files in the folder, append to the same data frame and export to csv or xls.

```py
import pandas as pd
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

path = r"C:\Users\dir\Desktop\FY23Indicators"
files = os.listdir(path)
print("Files and directories in '", path, "' :")
print(files)

path = r"C:\Users\dir\Desktop\FY23Indicators\*.pdf"

for files in (path, "rb"):
    reader = PdfReader(m)
    page = reader.pages[0]
    dictionary = reader.get_form_text_fields()
    series = pd.Series(dictionary).to_frame()
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(dictionary)).T
    pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)
    arrayofDF.append(df)
```

This code works for a single file text extraction, but I'd like to iterate through a folder of 12 files.

```py
reader = PdfReader(r"C:\Users\dir\Desktop\FY23Indicators\my file.pdf")
dictionary = reader.get_form_text_fields()
# Create DataFrame from simple dictionary i.e dictionary with key and simple value like integer or string value.
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dictionary.items()))
# set display max so text doesn't truncate
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)
```

Any advice?

Comment: There are at least two questions in here: (1) How do I get all PDF files in a folder (2) How do I extract text from a fillable form. You need to focus on one issue. Where is the actual problem?

Comment: Side note: If you're using PyPDF2 >= 1.28.0, you should use `PdfReader` instead of `PdfFileReader` and the snake_case methods instead of camelCase methods.

Comment: Thank you @MartinThoma. The problem is with getting all the extracted text into the same data frame. I'm able to successfully extract it from 1 pdf document. It's the same form, but different responses, all stored in the same path and folder. I want to be able to loop through each form and append the answers to a data frame. I hope I'm explaining it clearly. Also, thanks for the tip about PdfFileReader.

Comment: So your question is mainly about Pandas? Could it be rephrased to "How do I convert a list of dictionaries to a pandas dataframe"? This way we would remove the PyPDF2 part and the file system interaction part from the question. You can still ask separate questions for those two aspects. If it's that, please edit your question to contain a minimal example

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it needs more focus. Just ask one of the 3 aspects in one question.

Comment: I've just cleaned up your code, but there are still several things being bronken: (1) What is the variable `m`? I guess you forgot a loop `for m in files`. (2) `for files in (path, "rb")` is very likely not doing what you want - I guess you missed a `glob` (3) `arrayofDF` was never defined

Comment: Thank you, @MartinThoma. I'm still trying to get the hang of writing my code in order. After your initial comment about separating my issues into 3 different questions, and suggesting I edit to "How do I convert a list of dictionaries to a pandas dataframe" I went on the hunt for more info. I realized I will need 2 loops for this. I'm going to work on this now. I'll report back with the final code so that others may learn. Thanks, again! You're right, there are a few things wrong here, but you've been very helpful!

Answer (score -2):

You can use `os` library
visit [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-using-python/)

Comment: Thank you, Sefineh I am using the os library, but the code I have isn't working. I'm pretty new to coding. Is someone able to suggest tweaks to my code to get me going? I read the documentation and I'm still stuck.